# How bad is it for the performance to use 100s of inline SVGs? (Need to style them with CSS)

Tags: html, css, performance, svg, custom-font

The SVGs in question are tiny logos, delete buttons, check buttons and so on and I want to reuse them very often on the same page. Is that an acceptable way to deal with this or should I create something like a custom font?

Comment: Why not use the F12 Developer Tools' `Network Tab` to debug **exactly** how long it is taking your browser to load the various SVGs?

Comment: Here's a good breakdown: https://css-tricks.com/icon-fonts-vs-svg/

Comment: You can definitely do that and 100 should not be a problem unless you "animate" them all to move around etc. Caveat is in how complex your logos are. Basically SVGs = DOM - the more complicated dom is an the more changes / reflows etc you need to do with those - the worse the performance.